# How many string objects are created for the following?

Tags: java, string

```
String summer = new String("Summer");
String summer2 = "Summer";
System.out.println("Summer");
System.out.println("autumn");
System.out.println("autumn" == "summer");
String autumn = new String("Summer");
```

my answer is 2+0+0+1+1+1=5. is it correct?

Comment: I guess it will be only 3.

Comment: It can't be 2, since there's at least *three* different Strings here...

Comment: @Makoto `String summer2 = "Summer";` is a String literal.

Comment: @Makoto yes i corrected my comment

Comment: Note that "Summer" and "summer" are different. So yes, 5 is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds reasonable for me.

```
String summer = new String("Summer");
```

2 instances are created. The first is literal `"Summer"`. The second is because constructor is called.

```
String summer2 = "Summer";
```

0 instances: this is just a reference assignment.

```
System.out.println("Summer");
```

0 instances. The literal `"Summer"` is taken from cache.

```
System.out.println("autumn");
```

1 instance `"autumn"`

```
System.out.println("autumn" == "summer");
```

1 instance `"summer"`

```
String autumn = new String("Summer");
```

1 instance caused by constructor invocation. The literal `"Summer"` is taken from cache.

Bottom line:  2+0+0+1+1+1=5

Comment: In Java 7, it creates string literals on demand, but in Java 6 it does it on class loading which might change you answer.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be minimum 5? In the two cases where it doesn't create new instances, but relays on string pooling, isn't that just a compiler optimization that's undefined behaviour? I didn't think this behaviour was documented or demanded for a Java compiler.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I did not know about this difference between java 6 and 7. Could you please explain more or send some link?

Comment: oh! I thought all "Summer" will use the constant pool and refer to the same object. So, if you use new String(), it will not use String pool?

Comment: @karim, exactly. The constant pool is implemented in java somewhere into `String.valueOf()`. The string literals are compiled as calls of this method, so they use the cache. However there is no way to prevent creating new object when `new` keyword is used.

Comment: `String a = (new String("H") + "ello"); String b = a.intern(); String c = "Hello";` in Java 6 `a != b && b == c`, In Java 7 `a == b && b == c`

Answer (score 1):

Yes thats correct. In all, 5 objects will be created.

```
String summer = new String("Summer"); // 2 objects. One for constructor and other for literal
String summer2 = "Summer";  // 0. Will point to the literal already created.
System.out.println("Summer"); // 0. Same as above statement
System.out.println("autumn"); // 1 object will be created
System.out.println("autumn" == "summer"); // 1 object. 'Summer' and 'summer' are not same
String autumn = new String("Summer"); // 1 object. new String() will cause a new object creation but not the literal
```

Answer (score 1):

Compile it and count :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
public class test {
    private static Unsafe unsafe;

    static {
        try {
            Field field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            unsafe = (Unsafe) field.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static long addressOf(Object o) throws Exception {
        Object[] array = new Object[]{o};

        long baseOffset = unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class);
        int addressSize = unsafe.addressSize();
        long objectAddress;
        switch (addressSize) {
            case 4:
                objectAddress = unsafe.getInt(array, baseOffset);
                break;
            case 8:
                objectAddress = unsafe.getLong(array, baseOffset);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error("unsupported address size: " + addressSize);
        }

        return (objectAddress);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
            throws Exception {

        String summer = new String("Summer");
        System.out.println("Addess: " + addressOf(summer));
        String summer2 = "Summer";
        System.out.println("Addess: " + addressOf(summer2));
        System.out.println("Addess: " + addressOf("Summer"));
        System.out.println("Addess: " + addressOf("autumn"));
        System.out.println("Addess: " + addressOf("autumn"));
        System.out.println("Addess: " + addressOf("summer"));
        //System.out.println("Summer");
        //System.out.println("autumn");
        //System.out.println("autumn" == "summer");
        String autumn = new String("Summer");
        System.out.println("Addess: " + addressOf(autumn));


    }

    public static void printBytes(long objectAddress, int num) {
        for (long i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            int cur = unsafe.getByte(objectAddress + i);
            System.out.print((char) cur);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```